# How to make a matrix to the power of a number under some conditions without using loops in Python?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, matrix

I would like to compute this simple code in python, given a matrix modify it according to its entries. If the `(i, j)-th` entry is greater than or equal to `1` then make it to the power of `a` else make it `1`.

```
import numpy 

def restricted_power(k, n, d, a):
    """
    :param d: a distance matrix
    :param k, n: shape of d
    :param a: a positive real number 
    :return: a modified distance matrix 
    """
    x = numpy.zeros((k,n))
    for i in range(k):
        for j in range(n):
            if d[i, j] < 1:
                x[i, j] = 1
            else: 
                x[i, j] = d[i, j] ** a
    return x
```

Is there a way to code this without the loops ?

Comment: What is x? Why would you like to solve this without a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's not possible to do it without loops at some point, but you can push the looping to the C layer with numpy.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> example = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)/4.0
>>> example
array([[ 0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ],
       [ 0.75,  1.  ,  1.25],
       [ 1.5 ,  1.75,  2.  ]])
>>> a = 2 # sample exponent
>>> np.where(example < 1, 1, example**a)
array([[ 1.    ,  1.    ,  1.    ],
       [ 1.    ,  1.    ,  1.5625],
       [ 2.25  ,  3.0625,  4.    ]])
```